# Snakemake files in multiple directories

Tags: snakemake

My {dir} is a variable=/nameX/tissueX/trimmed
This is the code I use:

```
HISAT2_INDEX_PREFIX = "/index/genome_chromosomes"

directories, SAMPLES=glob_wildcards('/test/{dir}/{sample}_1.fastq.gz')
rule all:
    input: 
        expand("{dir}/{sample}.bam", zip, dir=directories, sample=SAMPLES)
rule hisat2:
    input:
        hisat2_index=expand("%s.{ix}.ht2l" % HISAT2_INDEX_PREFIX, ix=range(1, 9)),
        fastq1="/test/{dir}/{sample}_1.fastq.gz",
        fastq2="/test/{dir}/{sample}_1.fastq.gz"
    output:
        bam = "{dir}/{sample}.bam",
        txt = "{dir}/{sample}.txt",
    log: "{dir}/{sample}.snakemake_log.txt"
    threads: 2
    shell:
        "hisat2 -p {threads} -x {HISAT2_INDEX_PREFIX}"
        " -1 {input.fastq1} -2 {input.fastq2}  --summary-file {output.txt} |"
        "samtools sort -@ {threads} -o {output.bam}"
```

How to modify in the way to add nameX prefix to each bam file, and save all bam files in the same directory? And create for the same nameX one single bam file?